# Devestator II keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware

So I just converted over to Ubuntu today. However my keyboard back light is not working is there a way to install the drivers on Ubuntu? One person recommended doing this but I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it does not seem to be working. Any ideas or suggestions that do not involve buying another keyboard?

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same keyboard. Open terminal and type:

```
xset led on
```

This is essentially what the instructions say in the link you posted, but without the unnecessary steps. To automate it, search for Startup Applications, then create a new entry. Copy the command above into the command field, and give it any name and comment you want.

Comment: Now another issue just recently came into play my number pad refuses to work. Did that happen to you as well?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Glad to know I'm not the only one experiencing it. See my question and answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029541/mouse-keys-can-only-be-disabled-for-current-session