# Enable/disable universal access mouse keyboard keys, it's different (led keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keyboard-backlight

First of all, let me say that it is different. I've found the "solution" present in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113171/turn-mousekeys-on-off-from-keyboard) but it does not work for me, probably because I'm using a led keyboard in Ubuntu. So let me explain:

Ubuntu version: *18.04.5 LTS* Keyboard: *CM Storm Devastator*.

It's troublesome I usually need to run the command `xset led on`
to enable light in my keyboard, while also <kbd>numlock</kbd> and <kbd>scrlock</kbd> light doesn't work in Ubuntu.

When I turn on the LEDs using that command my numeric keyboard stop working and it turns into mouse keyboard (it turns off the numlock), but if I access to *Universal Controls* it is disabled (last option - mouse keys):

[image]

I have to manually turn it on, and then I have to turn it off.

**Note**: If I disable LEDs using `xset led off`, the numeric pad works fine. I need both. Numeric pad and LEDs.
My target is to be able to change the last option in this image to enable/disable it using the terminal.

Does anybody see that problem and found the solution?

**Edit**: I've also tried `setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys, keypad:legacy and numepad:pc`, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What make and model of keyboard?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Keyboard cm storm devastator, but I hope it will change soon

Comment: Please put that info in the question.